# TypeError: in method '...', argument 1 of type 'unsigned char const *' when using swig module

Tags: python, swig

Consider this little swig mcve:

**example.h**

```
void init(int width, int height);
void dump(const unsigned char *buffer,int pitch);
```

**example.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>

void init(int width, int height) {
    printf("Initializing width=%d height=%d", width, height);
}

void dump(const unsigned char *buffer,int pitch) {
    for(int i=0;i<pitch;i++) {
        printf("%d\n", buffer[i]);
    }
}
```

**example.i**

```
%module example

%{
#include "example.h"
%}

%include "example.h"
```

**setup.py**

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension


example_module = Extension('_example',
                            sources=['example.i', 'example_wrap.c', 'example.c'],
                            swig_opts = [],
                            include_dirs = ["."],
                           )

setup(name='example',
      version='0.1',
      author="BPL",
      description="""Mcve stackoverflow""",
      ext_modules=[example_module],
      py_modules=["example"]
    )
```

**test.py**

```
import struct
import example as swig_thing

count = 256
width = 8
height = 4

swig_thing.init(width, height)

for frame in range(count):
    print(f"frame {frame}")

    data = []
    for y in range(height):
        for x in range(width):
            data.append(0x00FF0000)
    _buffer = struct.pack(f'{len(data)}L', *data)
    swig_thing.dump(_buffer, width*4)
```

If I run `python setup.py build_ext --inplace` and then I try to run test.py I'll get the following error:

```
TypeError: in method 'dump', argument 1 of type 'unsigned char const *'
```

Question, how to avoid the above error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`struct.pack` can be used to create byte string buffers.  Let's say you have four integers to pack as four unsigned long values (16 bytes).  `pack` takes a format string.  `'4L'` means pack four unsigned longs in native-endian format.  Use `'<4L'` for little-endian and `'>4L'` for big-endian.

```
>>> import struct
>>> struct.pack('4L',1,2,3,4) # Direct way.
b'\x01\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00'

>>> data = [1,2,3,4] # Handle variable length...
>>> struct.pack('{}L'.format(len(data)),*data) 
b'\x01\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00'

>>> struct.pack(f'{len(data)}L',*data) # Python 3.6+
b'\x01\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00'
```

Exercise for you to generate the data list

Per your MCVE, add the following typemap to your SWIG interface to understand `unsigned char *`:

**example.i**

```
%module example

%{
#include "example.h"
%}

%typemap(in) (const unsigned char* buffer) (char* buffer, Py_ssize_t length) %{
  if(PyBytes_AsStringAndSize($input,&buffer,&length) == -1)
    SWIG_fail;
  $1 = (unsigned char*)buffer;
%}

%include "example.h"
```

Comment: That's due to no typemap defined in SWIG for `unsigned char *`.

Comment: @BPL I updated my answer.  Note for next time changing the title and question drastically warrants a new question.  My initial answer doesn't make sense in the new context.

Comment: @BPL But the MCVE was much appreciated!

Comment: @BPL I tried your code.  I didn't realize "pitch" (or "linepitch" in your uploaded code) wasn't the full buffer length.  I changed the example.i above to only convert the buffer pointer.  Pass "pitch" as width*4 and your code will work.  I was able to build the code at your aviwriter link and generate an .avi file.

Comment: In case you're interested on this subject, I've created a little mcve attempting to render audio/video. To check it out 1) git clone github.com/brupelo/aviwriter 2) python setup.py build_ext --inplace 3) python test.py -audio=0 , that will generate the video just fine. But when I try to also generate the audio `python test.py -audio=1` the resulting video file will be broken and I'm not sure why, got any idea what I'm doing wrong? you think the problem lives in the python code or in the swig file?

Comment: Guess asking a different question here wasn't fair so I've opened a new thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50212416/bug-writing-audio-using-custom-video-writer-library)

Comment: I am new to SWIG, I am using an existent code. I ignore then what is `example.i`. I should change/create this `.i` file to work with `unsigned char *` in SWIG? there is no other option?