# Bug writing audio using custom video writer library

Tags: python, c++, windows, audio, swig

I'm trying to wrap a little handy piece of C++ code that is intended to generate video+audio on Windows using VFW, the C++ library lives [here](http://www.farbrausch.de/%7Efg/code/aviwriter/) and the descriptions says:

> Uses Video for Windows (so it's not portable). Handy if you want to
> quickly record a video somewhere and don't feel like wading through
> the VfW docs yourself.

I'd like to use that C++ library on Python so I've decided to wrap it up using swig.

Thing is, I'm having some problems when it comes to encode the audio, for some reason I'm trying to understand why the generated video is broken, it seems the audio has not been written properly in the video file. That means, if I try to open the video with VLC or any similar video player I'll get a message saying the video player can't identify the audio or video codec. The video images are fine so it's definitely a problem with the way I'm writing the audio to the file.

I'm attaching both the swig interface and a little Python test that's trying to be a port of the original [c++ test](http://www.farbrausch.de/%7Efg/code/aviwriter/test.cpp).

**aviwriter.i**

```
%module aviwriter

%{
#include "aviwriter.h"
%}

%typemap(in) (const unsigned char* buffer) (char* buffer, Py_ssize_t length) %{
  if(PyBytes_AsStringAndSize($input,&buffer,&length) == -1)
    SWIG_fail;
  $1 = (unsigned char*)buffer;
%}

%typemap(in) (const void* buffer) (char* buffer, Py_ssize_t length) %{
  if(PyBytes_AsStringAndSize($input,&buffer,&length) == -1)
    SWIG_fail;
  $1 = (void*)buffer;
%}


%include "aviwriter.h"
```

**test.py**

```
import argparse
import sys
import struct
from distutils.util import strtobool

from aviwriter import AVIWriter


if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("-audio", action="store", default="1")
    parser.add_argument('-width', action="store",
                        dest="width", type=int, default=400)
    parser.add_argument('-height', action="store",
                        dest="height", type=int, default=300)
    parser.add_argument('-numframes', action="store",
                        dest="numframes", type=int, default=256)
    parser.add_argument('-framerate', action="store",
                        dest="framerate", type=int, default=60)
    parser.add_argument('-output', action="store",
                        dest="output", type=str, default="checker.avi")

    args = parser.parse_args()

    audio = strtobool(args.audio)
    framerate = args.framerate
    num_frames = args.numframes
    width = args.width
    height = args.height
    output = args.output

    writer = AVIWriter()

    if not writer.Init(output, framerate):
        print("Couldn't open video file!")
        sys.exit(1)

    writer.SetSize(width, height)

    data = [0]*width*height
    sampleRate = 44100
    samples_per_frame = 44100 / framerate
    samples = [0]*int(samples_per_frame)

    c1, s1, f1 = 24000.0, 0.0, 0.03
    c2, s2, f2 = 1.0, 0.0, 0.0013

    for frame in range(num_frames):
        print(f"frame {frame}")

        i = 0
        for y in range(height):
            for x in range(width):
                on = ((x + frame) & 32) ^ ((y+frame) & 32)
                data[i] = 0xffffffff if on else 0xff000000
                i += 1
        writer.WriteFrame(
            struct.pack(f'{len(data)}L', *data),
            width*4
        )

        if audio:
            for i in range(int(samples_per_frame)):
                c1 -= f1*s1
                s1 += f1*c1
                c2 += f2*s2
                s2 -= f2*c2

                val = s1 * (0.75 + 0.25 * c2)
                if(frame == num_frames - 1):
                    val *= 1.0 * (samples_per_frame - 1 - i) / \
                        samples_per_frame
                samples[i] = int(val)

                if frame==0:
                    print(f"i={i} val={int(val)}")

            writer.WriteAudioFrame(
                struct.pack(f'{len(samples)}i', *samples),
                int(samples_per_frame)
            )

    writer.Exit()
```

I don't think `samples` is being generated incorrectly as I've already compared the values generated on the python side with the values generated on the c++ side, just the packet written for frame 0 though.

Some of my suspicions about what's wrong is the way I've created the typemap on swig, maybe that's not good... or maybe the problem lives in the line `writer.WriteAudioFrame(struct.pack(f'{len(samples)}i', *samples), int(samples_per_frame))`, I don't know what could be, definitely the way I'm sending the audio buffer from Python to the C++ wrapper is not good.

So, would you know how to fix the attached code so test.py will be able to generate a video with the right audio similarly to the c++ test?

When generated ok, the video will display a magic scrolling checkerboard with hypnotic sinewaves as audio backdrop :D

**Additional notes:**

1. It seems the above code is not using `writer.SetAudioFormat` which is needed for the functions `AVIFileCreateStreamA` and `AVIStreamSetFormat`. Problem is I don't know how to export this structure on swig, that way I'd be able to use it on Python the same way than `test.cpp`, from Mmreg.h I've seen the structure looks like this:

   typedef struct tWAVEFORMATEX
   {
   WORD    wFormatTag;        /* format type */
   WORD    nChannels;         /* number of channels (i.e. mono, stereo...) */
   DWORD   nSamplesPerSec;    /* sample rate */
   DWORD   nAvgBytesPerSec;   /* for buffer estimation */
   WORD    nBlockAlign;       /* block size of data */
   WORD    wBitsPerSample;    /* Number of bits per sample of mono data */
   WORD    cbSize;            /* The count in bytes of the size of
   extra information (after cbSize) */

   } WAVEFORMATEX;

Unfortunately I don't know how to wrap that stuff on aviwriter.i? I've tried using %include windows.i and include the stuff directly on a block `%{`...`%}` but all I've got were a bunch of errors :/

2. I'd prefer not modifying neither aviwriter.h && aviwriter.cpp at all as that's basically external working code.
3. Assuming I'm able to wrap the `WAVEFORMATEX` so I can use it on Python, how'd you use memset similarly to `test.cpp`? ie: `memset(&wfx,0,sizeof(wfx));`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two suggestions:

- First, pack the data as `short` instead of `int` for the audio format, as per the C++ test.  Audio data is 16-bit, not 32-bit.  Use the 'h' extension for the packing format.  For example, `struct.pack(f'{len(samples)}h', *samples)`.
- Second, see code modification below.  Expose `WAVEFORMATX` via SWIG, by editing `aviwriter.i`.  Then call `writer.SetAudioFormat(wfx)` from Python.
- In my tests, the `memset()` was not necessary.  From python you could manually set the field `cbSize` to zero, that should be enough.  The other six fields are mandatory so you'll be setting them anyways.  It looks like this struct isn't meant to be revised in the future, because it does not have a struct size field, and also the semantics of `cbSize` (appending arbitrary data to the end of the struct) conflict with an extension anyways.

aviwriter.i:

```
%inline %{
typedef unsigned short WORD;
typedef unsigned long DWORD;
typedef struct tWAVEFORMATEX
{
    WORD    wFormatTag;        /* format type */
    WORD    nChannels;         /* number of channels (i.e. mono, stereo...) */
    DWORD   nSamplesPerSec;    /* sample rate */
    DWORD   nAvgBytesPerSec;   /* for buffer estimation */
    WORD    nBlockAlign;       /* block size of data */
    WORD    wBitsPerSample;    /* Number of bits per sample of mono data */    
    WORD    cbSize;            /* The count in bytes of the size of
                                extra information (after cbSize) */
} WAVEFORMATEX;
%}
```

test.py:

```
from aviwriter import WAVEFORMATEX
```

later in test.py:

```
    wfx = WAVEFORMATEX()
    wfx.wFormatTag = 1 #WAVE_FORMAT_PCM
    wfx.nChannels = 1
    wfx.nSamplesPerSec = sampleRate
    wfx.nAvgBytesPerSec = sampleRate * 2
    wfx.nBlockAlign = 2
    wfx.wBitsPerSample = 16
    writer.SetAudioFormat(wfx)
```

**Notes on SWIG:**  Since aviwriter.h only provides a forward declaration of `tWAVEFORMATEX`, no other information is provided to SWIG, preventing get/set wrappers from being generated.  You could ask SWIG to wrap a Windows header declaring the struct ... and open a can of worms because those headers are too large and complex, exposing further problems.  Instead, you can individually define `WAVEFORMATEX` as done above.  The C++ types `WORD` and `DWORD` still are not declared, though.  Including the SWIG file `windows.i` only creates wrappers which, for example, allow string "WORD" in a Python script file to be understood as indicating 16-bit data in memory.  But that doesn't declare the `WORD` type from a C++ perspective.  To resolve this, adding typedefs for `WORD` and `DWORD` in this `%inline` statement in `aviwriter.i` forces SWIG to copy that code directly inlined into the wrapper C++ file, making the declarations available.  This also triggers get/set wrappers to be generated.  Alternately, you could include that inlined code inside aviwriter.h if you're willing to edit it.

In short, the idea here is to fully enclose all types into standalone headers or declaration blocks.  Remember that .i and .h file have separate functionality (wrappers and data conversion, versus functionality being wrapped).  Similarly, notice how `aviwriter.h` is included twice in the `aviwriter.i`, once to trigger the generation of wrappers needed for Python, and once to declare types in the generated wrapper code needed for C++.

Comment: Updated the aviwriter.i code, and added Notes on SWIG to explain.  Generally yes, SWIG gets pretty confusing.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah, you're right, wrapping headers like windows.h sounds like a lot of additional problems, these headers usually have zillion dependencies so at the end I guess I'd waste a lot of time setting the right compiler options, let's go with your simpler approach. Only remaining thing is to see how this wrapper will behave with GPU generated content, as computing video data on python side has proven to be 10x slower, just compare test.cpp vs test.py to see what I mean. Btw, do you know how to avoid the video coded dialog? ie: which strings are used with `mmioFOURCC`? Anyway, tyvm!

Comment: I don't have an exhaustive list of codecs, and assume it depends on what's installed.  My system has: 'DIB '= [68,73,66,32] for uncompressed, 'i420'=[105,52,50,48], 'iyuv'=[105,121,117,118], 'msvc'=[109,115,118,99], 'mrle'=[109,114,108,101].  Also, for compressed formats you need a quality value.  I recommend setting a breakpoint after the `AVISaveOptions()` call and closing the dialog, to get the codec and quality you want as a default.  Pass those when calling `writer.Init()` in test.cpp using `mmioFOURCC`. Note the `quality` param is optional, not passed in the current code.

Answer (score 1):

From what I saw in the code you don't initialize the audio format. This is done in the original `test.cpp` code by calling `writer.SetAudioFormat(&wfx);` at line 44, then it is set for mono 44.1 kHz PCM. I believe that since you do not initialize, the blank header is written, and video player is unable to open the unknown format.

**Update**

As you only need to pass the binary header structure, and you don't need to use the structure and declare it in the `aviwriter.i`. You can use following code directly from Python:

```
import struct
from collection import namedtuple

WAVEFORMATEX = namedtuple('WAVEFORMATEX', 'wFormatTag nChannels nSamplesPerSec nAvgBytesPerSec nBlockAlign wBitsPerSample cbSize ')
wfx = WAVEFORMATEX(    
    wFormatTag = 1,
    nChannels = 1,
    nSamplesPerSec = sampleRate,
    nAvgBytesPerSec = sampleRate * 2,
    nBlockAlign = 2,
    wBitsPerSample = 16,
    cbSize = 0)

audio_format_obj = struct.pack('<HHIIHHH', *list(wfx))
writer.SetAudioFormat(audio_format_obj)
```

This will automatically solve your second and third concerns.

As for `memset(&wfx,0,sizeof(wfx));` this is just an ugly way of old C to zero all variables in the structure.

P.S. As @MichaelsonBritt mentioned, your audio data format have to match the declaration in the header. But instead of converting to 16 bit `short`, you can declare 2 channels, so you will get stereo sound with one channel silent.